# VBA Excel Divide Selection By 2

Tags: excel, vba

I want to divide a selected cell(s) by 2 and have a msg box with the final value.
For example I found this macro, where I select a cell, enter my short cut key and it tells me the sum of all the cells selected. I want to do the same but divide by 2

```
Sub MySum()
    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Selection)
End Sub
```

Comment: `MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Selection) / 2`

Comment: Thank you @Scott Craner